# *ngFor Changes the alignment of Components

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-directive

When I render my components just as in a div they are aligned horizontally, which I specified by adding the flexbox container class to the div in which they are stored in.

```
<div class="flexbox-container" >
  <app-card></app-card>
  <app-card></app-card>
  <app-card></app-card>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.flexbox-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[image]

However, when I add an input property to these components, and use a loop to display them they are stacked on top of each other.

```
<div class="flexbox-container" *ngFor="let title of titles" >
  <app-card title={{title}}></app-card>
</div>
```

[image]

My question is how can I change this so my components are aligned horizontally like they were before instead of vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are adding the ngFor in wrong place. The way you are coding it is creating 4 divs and placing a single element in each one. The code should be

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
     <app-card *ngFor="let title of titles" title={{title}}></app-card>
</div>
```

Please mark it as answer if it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Yes, that worked. I wonder why we don't use the square brackets for the property binding syntax when we do it this way

Comment: If I am not wrong app-card is a custom component. So if you want to write [title]='title' angular will consider title as an @Input() in the app-card component.